# Dynamic Column Sizing in Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation 5 to build a site. My site has a navigation panel against the left side of the screen. When open, I want the nav area to take up 3 columns. The actual content will take up the remaining space. Here is the HTML I have thus far:

```
<body>
  <div style="width:100%; max-width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div id="navDiv" class="large-3 columns" style="background-color:#2D2D2D;height:100%;">
      <!-- Nav Items Go Here -->
    </div>
    <div class="large-9 columns">
      <!-- Main Content Goes Here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Each nav item has an icon and some text. I need to be able to collapse the navDiv in a way that it shrinks down so that only the icons are showing. The text goes away. At the same time, I need the main content area to grow to take up the space that was used by the nav area. I cannot figure out how to do this in the realm of zurb. From what I can tell, the grid is not dynamic. Is it possible to do what I'm trying with a grid? If so, how?

THank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why your columns aren't in a `.row`?

Comment: What event do you want to trigger the resize? For example, going from a 'large' viewport to 'medium' or clicking on an icon.

Comment: @tyler - clicking on an icon. chrona - because I overlooked it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Foundation (with jQuery dependency) and no other add-ons, you can use a jQuery event handler to toggle the classes used by Foundation. It feels like a hack, but it works.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button>Toggle sidebar</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="navDiv" class="small-2 medium-1 columns">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/48"><span>Item 1</span>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="small-10 medium-11 columns">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.small-2 span {
    /* Hide text when sidebar is small */
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript + jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        // Resize sidebar
        var navDiv = $('#navDiv');
        navDiv.toggleClass('small-3');
        navDiv.toggleClass('small-2');
        navDiv.toggleClass('medium-2');
        navDiv.toggleClass('medium-1');

        // Resize content
        var content = $('#content');
        content.toggleClass('small-9');
        content.toggleClass('small-10');
        content.toggleClass('medium-10');
        content.toggleClass('medium-11');
    });
});
```

**[Demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ewaWy5l7Q8LK8QTt3CyT?p=preview)**

Comment: I thought about doing that. That's the best I could come up with as well. I was hoping to make it relative so I could animate the navDiv shrinking. Do you have any ideas around that? Either way, you answered the question posted. For that reason, I'm awarding you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! Foundation will change `width` when, for example, the class changes from `small-3` to `small-2`. If you add `transition: width 1s ease;` in the CSS (with the appropriate vendor prefixes, or [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)), you can animate the sidebar.